# Mongoose adds new entry to the array on $set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am updating an array on the courses document. The name of the array is quizCards. The array index is set to the variable 'i'. However after the modification mongodb will always have an additional  copy of the modified array element at the end. How can i keep the array the same size just modifying the element with the given index.

```
router.post("/editCard", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.cardId)
  let i = req.body.cardId;
  Course.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.courseId }, {$set: { ["quizCards." + i + ".title"]: req.body.title }})
    .then(respData => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: respData
      })
    })
  })
```

I tried to add new:false. It did not work.

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` only returns the document and not the array of documents. Where are you creating an array?

Comment: document is courses and it has an array named quizCards. Actually the set method works and it modifies the element on the given index but it adds a new copy of the modified element at the end of the array that is my problem.

Comment: Ah right I had misunderstood. For immutability's sake, I'd advise replacing the entire array as opposed to only modifying one element, especially as opposed to using an index. What happens if someone else has made a change since you pulled the data? You seem to be assuming that the array index is identical to `cardId`. That doesn't seem robust. Is there any reason not to have `quizCards` be a different collection and only use `_id` values in `Course`?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Actually I may use the _id to fetch and replace but I send the array index to backend from user  to edit the card that is currently in focus very easily and I suppose that I'm very close to handle the problem and I'm missing a simple fact since I am a beginner.